# Given function $f(x)$ and $m\in \Bbb{R}$, for what values of $m$ is $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Given function $f(x)$ and $m\in \Bbb{R}$, for what values of $m$ is $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$?
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
(m-1)x+m & \text{for } x<1\\ 
x^2+(m-2)x+4-2m & \text{for } x \geq 1
\end{cases} 
$$

Comment: @RoryDaulton Do you mean "for what values of m is f(x)≥0f(x)≥0 for all x∈R?" Yes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of the question. Now I must ask, what work have you done on the question so far? Just where are you stuck? Do you know how to find the minimum value of a quadratic expression?

Comment: @RoryDaulton I am trying to get a feeling of the function. I am stuck at determining where to start the proof and what techniques there should be involved. I found this equation out of context, I am not quite sure what to expect.

Comment: As I implied, you start by finding the minimum value of the quadratic expression inside the function definition, which will depend on $m$. Do you know how to do that? (There are some details to add, of course.) Without you explaining more what you have tried, this question will probably be closed.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Are you suggesting to find the roots of the derivative? I know how to do that. I am not sure about the first step, so I would appreciate if you could give me a clear direction. Thanks.

Comment: No derivative is needed, just complete the square. See my answer below for more: this is getting too much for comments. But you need to do more work of your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $x<1$ we need $$(m-1)x+m\geq 0.\qquad (*)$$

If $m-1>0$ then the LHS of $(*)$ is linearly increasing and so negative for small enough $x$. Thus we need $m\leq 1$, in which case the LHS is weakly decreasing and so $(*)$ is satisfied for all $x<1$ as long as it is satisfied at $x=1$. At $x=1$, inequality $(*)$ becomes $$2m-1\geq0.$$ So we also need $m\geq 1/2$.

When $x\geq 1$ we have $$f'(x)=2x+m-2$$ so that the minimizer of the quadratic on $\mathbb{R}$ is $\bar{x}=1-m/2$. Since $m\in[1/2,1]$, we have $\bar{x}<1$, so that $f$ is increasing when $x\geq 1$. Thus it is enough that $$1^2+(m-2)1+4-2m=3-m\geq 0$$

which holds because we already required $m\in[1/2,1]$.

Comment: If $m \geq 1/2$ then only will $2m-1>0$ hold; so basically $1/2$ must be slightly smaller for $2m-1\geq 0$ to hold? For $x\geq 1$ the lower bound is $\frac{6}{13}$ therefore the lower bound is forced by the definition in range $x<1$. So basically, the lower bound $1/2$ is slightly too high to account for $2m-1=0$, therefore the proof proves only $f(x)>0$ instead of $f(x)\geq 0$?

Answer (score 0):

We prove that $\dfrac{1}{2} \le m \le 1$ is the answer. Pick $x = 0 \implies m = f(0) \ge 0$, and if $m > 1$ then $f(x) < 0$ for $x$ large and negative. Thus $0 \le m \le 1$. For $0 \le m \le 1$, and for $x \ge 1$, $f'(x) = 2(x-1) + m \ge 0 \implies f(x) \ge f(1) =3-m \ge 0$. Also if $x < 1 \implies f'(x) = m - 1 < 0 \implies f(x) > f(1) = 2m - 1 \ge 0$ for $m \ge \dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Can you also think of a deductive proof? I am not a fan of guess & try, even though it works too... Thanks for your input.

Answer (score -1):

**HINTS:**

The second part of your function definition is a quadratic expression, so you need to find its minimum value, which will depend on $m$. The general quadratic can be rewritten by completing the square,

$$q(x)=ax^2+bx+c=a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\left(c-\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)$$

So if $a$ is positive, the expression has the minimum value of $c-\frac{b^2}{4a}$ at $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$. Those values are attained at the vertex of the parabola of the graph of the quadratic expression.

You can find the minimum value and location by using your particular values of $a,b,c$, which are expression of $m$. Now since your quadratic is limited to $x\ge 1$, you need to distinguish two cases: (1) where the vertex is to the right of $x=1$ so the values I gave are indeed for your minimum, or (2) where the vertex is to the left of $x=1$, so the minimum value is attained at $x=1$ since the vertex of the parabola is never realized in your function.

That gives you two kinds of minima, which give you two limitations on $m$. Last, check the linear part of your function definition and find its minimum value, if any. The combination of all those restrictions on $m$ is your final answer.